# Any good alternatives to Notepad++ for code editing in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, php, html, css, notepadqq

what are the good alternatives to Notepad++ for code editing in Lubuntu? I'm a web designer mostly wanting a good editor for php, html and css editing. I've been using Notepad++ on Windows so something similar will be nice. But I'm ready to tryout other programs which maybe different or have better features. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for just an editor or there is some feature of Notepad++ that you need?

Comment: migrc, just an editor. i tried out gedit. it look ok. I guess i need to get used to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three that come to mind quickly.

1. [Atom](https://atom.io/)
2. [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Atom is the new kid on the block. Atom is made by the people over at github. You can coutomize it to your hearts content. Atom is fully free, and will never ask you for money.

Sublime Text is the old man in the group. Sublime has been around for a long time. This is the editor that I started with even before I started to use Linux. You can fully customize Sublime and make it look however you want. Sublime is a free text editor but after 30 or 60 days i forget which it will start to ask you to buy a license. If you wait a minute or so you can click cancel and keep using it.

Comment: Thanks Will, I will check it out. Sublime sounds great but with those prompts it can become tiresome.

Comment: If you are working as a web designer, making money, maybe it's an idea to support the software developers either by buying a license or donating a little share of your income. Especially since the Sublime rates are relatively fair, to be honest, should you choose to use it.

Comment: So, uh, you said "three" come to mind quickly...what was the third one?

Comment: no there is a third one but I don't know that much about Microsoft's Visual Studio Code. I should have proof read that before I posted.

Answer (score 3):

Use Sublime Text or Brackets. Brackets is more focussed on web development with live preview features which help a lot. you can download both of them from their website, they give .deb packages directly

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for primarily php, html, and css, go for [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). It is definitely one of the best web development apps out there that is available for Linux. It advertises Javascript, but it's amazing for all things web development.

Otherwise, code wide - I use gedit, which only highlights / colorizes the code source much like Notepad++ will. Extremely useful for random programs, quick editing, etc.

Comment: yes, gedit seems ok. color codes are different somuch get used to it i guess

Comment: Initially, the coloring is different, but you can enable different "themes" in the preferences. [Here is an entire article](https://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/how-to-convert-gedit-to-gedit/) on how to get gedit to look like Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already familair with Notepad++ I would recommend Notepadqq.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notepadqq
```

Note: this apparently won't work on Ubuntu 12.04